# Populate listbox with associated entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I'm building my first MVC(3) application which manages snippets.

Obviously I have an edit page for a snippet, which has a programming language (0.* to 0.1).

Now my question is, how can I build a listbox with all the present programming languages to show on my edit page for a snippet?

I think I can create a ViewModel and populate that with all the values by querying them manually and passing them as a list, but I have a feeling that the people who built MVC have a tidier solution to this? I have "Pro MVC 3" and "Pro Entity Framework" at hand by Apress but can't seem to find an answer to this.

When I try:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Language or model.Language.Name)
```

I get errors.

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do in similar cases:
1) Create a View Model for editing language

```
 public class LanguagesModel
{

    public IEnumerable<int> SelectedLanguageIds { get; set; }
    public MultiSelectList languages { get; set; }
}
```

2) Populate the model in the controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Language> languages = _languageService.GetLanguages();//however you get  the languages from your datasource
         var temp = new MultiSelectList(
                            languages.Select(l => new { Value =  l.LanguageId.ToString(), Text = l.Name }),
                            "Value",
                            "Text");

        LanguagesModel model = new LanguagesModel();
        model.languages = temp;



        return View(model);
    }
```

3) Create a view that uses the DropDownListFor helper:

```
@model LanguagesModel

 @using (Html.BeginForm(Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype      = "multipart/form-data" })))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
     @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedLanguageIds, Model.languages)


<p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</p>
</fieldset>
}
```

be carefule to replace "Index" and "Home" by the Action and Controllers that you are actually using.

**Edit** Changed code to use ListBox instead of DropDownList. Inspired by Darin Dimitrov's answer

Answer (score 0):

> I think I can create a ViewModel

Straight to the point! That's exactly what I would recommend you doing.

But if you want to stick with your domain models you could do some adaptations in the view in order to be able to use the ListBox helper (totally unrecommended solution, but since you asked for something more *tidier* according to your criteria):

```
@model Snippet
@Html.ListBox(
    "SelectedIds", 
    new MultiSelectList(
        Model.Languages.Select(l => new { Value = l.ID.Tostring(), Text = l.Name }),
        "Value",
        "Text"
    )
)
```